# When is it appropriate to subclass NSMergePolicy?

Tags: ios, core-data

I've written a small framework that syncs CoreData objects to an SQL backend on my server and I'm using a subclass of `NSManagedObject` to add the sync-related metadata (eg: `someObject.sync_status = needsSync`) to each object. The sync routine is called periodically and changes this metadata on a separate context in the background without involving the user.

If the sync routine is called while the user is actively editing and saving objects in an `NSManagedObjectContext`, the user's version of the metadata is likely to be stale and will conflict with the current metadata saved in the background context. My solution to this is to listen for and merge changes from the background context save notifications, though I would prefer to avoid this complexity outside of the framework.

I'm wondering if a custom merge policy would solve this at the framework layer by ignoring the user's version of the metadata properties, and all other properties would be subject to the `NSMergePolicyType` as usual (the default `NSErrorMergePolicyType` would probably still be the most useful for me). I've tried to subclass `NSMergePolicy` and override `resolveConflicts:error:`, but I can't figure out how it's supposed to work and I find zero examples online.

My questions are:
 - Am I on the right track with this merge policy idea? 
 - If so, how do I resolve conflicts inside my `resolveConflicts:error:` override?

Thank you!